# I'm trying to access local hyperledger test-network chaincodes through nodejs, for writing apis

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I have followed this for setting up the test-network and deploying the chaincodes
[hlf test-network setup](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/test_network.html) till querying the chaincode step
I can query them using peer command from terminal but I want to query them through my api, for that I'm following this: [first hlf application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/write_first_app.html)
But I'm facing this issue while running enrolladmin.js
[image: error]
These are my containers:
[image: Containers]

1. Do I need to Bring up the network with Certificate Authorities, is it necessary ?
2. Is this a port problem? If yes, from where should I change and what?
3. I just want to write an api to query, update the chaincode ledger, is there any better way?

Please guide me, I'm a newbie in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To have better idea onto writing Node SDK applications for HLF, you can closely follow the `fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript` directory. I think you would need connection profile for the network to successfully run these applications.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing up the network with Certificate Authorities, solved my primary error.